# ImageView fit without stretching the image

Tags: android, android-layout, uiimageview, imageview

is it possible that my `ImageView` will fit to all screen sizes without the image look stretched?

i tried all scale types changing it to background and src with `fill_parent` > `wrap_content`

but still. if the image is not smaller it just looks stretched..

example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

these 2 fits the width but the image is stretched.. but when i change it to src the image is just centered and small.

Comment: You are asking for something that is most obviously impossible. Unless of course, the image and the screen/view you want to cram it into happen to have identical aspect ratios.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no built-in scale type that allows the `ImageView` to automatically upscale the image *and* keep its aspect ratio intact. The only scale type that does upscaling is `fitXY`, which won't respect the aspect ratio, as you found out yourself too.

That being said, this topic has already been visited more than once. Have a look at some of the proposed suggestions for similar questions:

- [ImageView one dimension to fit free space and second evaluate to keep aspect ration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202000/imageview-one-dimension-to-fit-free-space-and-second-evaluate-to-keep-aspect-rat)
- [Fit image into ImageView, keep aspect ratio and then resize ImageView to image dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d)
- [Resizing ImageView to fit to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400113/resizing-imageview-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio)

I'm sure'll be heaps more, so it might worth using the search box at the top.

Comment: upvoted thanks MH... arghh. seems like its impossible. =_= to fix in xml~ adjusting the width to fit the screen really stretches the image

Comment: i have accepted your answer. i found out in another topic that you cant do this only on xml.. you must fix it in java.. thank you~

Answer (score 13):

You can do it by just adding just one attributes to ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for the right answer for so long using the scale type. but this one line made it really easy. Thanks a lot