# Make an android activity look and act like android main screen background

Tags: java, android

I need some help with an idea I had for an application I'm developing. 
I have a main activity, which has a background image that is wider than the screen, and I wanted to make that image look and act like the android main screen
 [image: Android main screen]

But I not being able to make the background ImageView to act like it.
Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
// slide effect in background
background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBackMain);
backgroundAnim = new TranslateAnimation(TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE,
        100f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f);
backgroundAnim.setDuration(10000);
backgroundAnim.setRepeatCount(-1);
backgroundAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
backgroundAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
background.setAnimation(backgroundAnim);
```

And here's my activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#088A08"
    tools:context="com.racsa.UI.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgBackMain"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/pantalla_principal"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnMain"
        android:onClick="goMaps"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lblLoginPopUp"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpenLoginOptions"
        android:onClick="openLoginOptions"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/lblTurismo"
        android:id="@+id/lblTurismo"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnOpenLoginOptions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my activity looks like at the moment (I've been trying with the setScaleType method, don't blame me lol)
[image: Main activity]

It doesn't matter if is done automatically or if I have to scroll myself, I just want to make it look and act like the android main screen background. I have also tried to put the image as a background for the Relative layout, with no success

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** 
After trying to add Sprockets to my project, I have an annoying Class not found error, in v4.view.ViewPager and I'm really starting to get nuts with this.
This is my dependencies module in the projects' Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    // Facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'net.sf.sprockets:sprockets-android:2.4.0'
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: iadd `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `ImageView`

Comment: If I do that, it fits, but the image gets stretched, not looking well :/

Comment: Than refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925530/imageview-fit-without-stretching-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android/blob/master/samples/images/TranslateImagePageChangeListener.gif)?  Check out [TranslateImagePageChangeListener](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/view/TranslateImagePageChangeListener.html), part of [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (disclosure: I'm the developer).

Comment: I was doing fine working with Sprockets(looks really cool btw), and I got this error saying "java finished with non-zero exit value 2" and I'm not being able to test the app, did I miss something?

Comment: If you can reproduce that error and it's related to the library, create an issue on GitHub and I'll look into it.  A screenshot would be nice as well, since I don't think I've seen that kind of error while working with an Android app and am not sure where it would appear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually fixed the error(my bad actually), now I'm struggling with some ViewPager recognition error, no biggie... I'll let you know when I'm actually into Sprockets

Comment: Hey dude! I haven't been able to get into sprockets. Android Studio just won't work with android support. I'm going to make a full reinstall to see whats up :(

Comment: Try removing `support-v4`, `gson`, and `play-services` from your `dependencies`.  Sprockets already includes all of those.  I've heard Android Studio/Gradle can get confused when dependencies are included multiple times.

Comment: Removed them, no success. I think I'm going back to Eclispe to finish this project, Android studio in this particular case is not working properly

Comment: I'm in eclipse again. Is there a way to import Sprockets there?

Comment: If you aren't using a dependency management system like Maven or Gradle, then it wouldn't be easy to set up manually because there are many dependencies in the tree.  If you only need `TranslateImagePageChangeListener`, you could just copy that class and `ObservableImageView` to your project.

Comment: I gave up. I finished using a custom viewpager, in eclipse, with a pretty close approach to sprockets. Even though, I'm going to add it to my bookmarks to try it later. Great project!