# Image with same resolution not fit on layout imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Problem: trying to give multi device support screen for a simple layout but in Nexus 6 its creating the problem,means not showing fit.
It's side is cutting down where as per as docs for nexus-6 resolution is 1440*2560 and image should be in drawable-xxxhdpi .so i keep a image with resolution of 1440*2560.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/imv" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if i ll give match_parent so obvious it will stretch the image.
Please help me to get out of it.
Here is screen shots of screen -

http://s10.postimg.org/43od5j5h5/screen_shot_layout.png

Comment: use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for fit image in `ImageView`

Comment: @ChiragSavsani i know but it will stretch the image if not match the resolution

Comment: Then try to use 9patch drawable if possible.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani image is not a kind of which can be make 9patch.is there any other way to use?like different folder or different image size?

Comment: have you tried (fiil_parent) instead of wrap_content?

Comment: set both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`

Comment: ya but its again stretching the image

Comment: no,  its  not  stretching

Comment: @pskink will stretch when you make it for full width

Comment: ok what do you mean by "stretch"? the aspect ratio will change?

Comment: set image width and height to 410 x 730 dp  -- that should sort it out if you say the image is the right size for the nexus 6 -- and use (android:scaleType="center") --- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.cy/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: @Tasos problem is not with the imageview because when you put it match_parent then it will go for the 410 in width but what size i have to give for the image.right now what you can see by the attached picture it is already at 1400 width and 2000 on height

Comment: @pskink yes its changing

Comment: ok then ill try a demo and run it in an emulator to see whats going on

Comment: no, aspect ration is not changing when using the scale type other than FIT_XY or MATRIX, and you are using the default scale type so aspect ratio will NOT change

Comment: @Tasos thanks i will wait for your truthfull response

Comment: @pskink can you show as screen shot what exactly looking as or code

Comment: ImageView iv = new ImageView(this); iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon); setContentView(iv);

Comment: Ok i think i know whats happening Nexus 6 is  1440*2560. however the Navigation Bar and status bar also take up some extra pixels hence why i think the image gets scaled. try hiding both and see and see if pic fits in nicely --- http://s21.postimg.org/jxtae4p6f/Capture.jpg

Comment: @Tasos you are going in right way,hope you can bring a solution.

Comment: yep, if im right i deserve a point cause screen size does not equal to content size in android cause of those bars they add on to the screen, although you can easyly hide them since kitcat -- you can see here what i mean -- http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php#Header253  - but they dont have Nexus 6 to check, but have a look at all the other Nexus

Comment: Did you try setting width to fill_parent, height to wrap_content and android:adjustViewBounds="true" ?

Comment: what do you mean a solution? email google and ask them (without the bars what are the exact dimensions of the content view for the Nexus 6 cause i went here http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php but they havent added it in yet). or ask on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of the Image to fill_parent (you can set margins if you want a bit smaller imageView or you could also just set a fixed width)

Use android:adjustViewBounds to keep aspect ratio

Set height to wrap_content (it will take whatever it takes to maintain aspect ratio)

```
<ImageView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:src="@drawable/icon"
       android:id="@+id/imv"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit the image on the imageview, replace android:src with android:background in the ImageView in the xml code.

Comment: Ok, Please go through the following links. Maybe they can help you solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925530/imageview-fit-without-stretching-the-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d

Comment: sorry it will not work, i need the way to keep image in drawable and exact resolution of image to show on nexus 6 device

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these lines of code in the layout

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imv" />
```

Comment: but it will stretch the image if not match the resolution as i have already mentioned above,is there any other way to match the criteria?