# fill server Image to NetworkImageview without Stretching it android

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-volley

**What I have**

I have `ImageUri` from server , & I am setting it to my `NetworkImageview` **Volley library**

**What I want**

I want the image to occupy full `width` & `height` of the `NetworkImageview` **(wanted similar to facebook)**

**My problem**

I see `width` of my `NetworkImageview` in white `colour` left

**My code**

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_profile_hotot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_profile_header"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_post_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/image_palce" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_profile_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/profile_footer_bg">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_photo_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_home_place"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                tools:text="Paris France" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_photo_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_photo_location"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:ems="40"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_very_small"
                tools:text="Effel Tower,...Read more" />
            />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_foot"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home_footstep_color"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_profile_comment" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_foot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                tools:text="150"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_profile_photo_description"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_profile_photo_description" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_cheers"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home_cheers_color"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_comment"
                android:layout_marginEnd="14dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_comment"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_home_coments"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_profile_comment" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                tools:text="264"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_profile_photo_description"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_profile_foot" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_cheers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
                tools:text="3164"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_profile_photo_description"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_comment" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```
myBucketListViewHolder.imgPostPic.setImageUrl(model.Uri, imageLoader);
        myBucketListViewHolder.imgPostPic.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.im_default_cover);
```

**screen shot :(**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

with

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

in your NetworkImageView

Comment: YOU have not posted your question clearly. Rephrase your problem, doesn't make much sense

Comment: If I use centerCrop, my full image won't be visible.

Comment: You want a square image to fit inside a rectangle without modifying aspect ratio ? or is it ok if image stretch? (Which isn't similar to facebook)

Comment: the image shouldn't stretch . I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202000/imageview-one-dimension-to-fit-free-space-and-second-evaluate-to-keep-aspect-rat

Comment: I would have answered immediately if you mentioned this in question. Any ways this is the cleanest solution in my opinion: https://github.com/solusoftinnova/app_android_carnavalea/blob/master/src/es/solusoft/santosinocentes/widget/ResizableImageView.java just extend it from NetworkImageView instead of ImageView

Comment: May I know what id does . it resizes my Imageview OR image ?

Comment: GOT " android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class utils.ResizableImageView "

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me using NetworkImageView the problem is that it behaves a little different to ImageView and not enough with `android: scaleType = "centerCrop"` to fill the width when the density of the screen is greater than the width of the image you want insert.
Try this code, at runtime change the width of the image adjusting it to the density of the screen.

In your layout.xml

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/imagePagerView"/>
```

In your activity (i have in adapter)

```
    Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    float scWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    float scHeigh = outMetrics.heightPixels;
    mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) scWidth;
    mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) scHeigh;
```